# XSLT 2.0 remove elements based on an attribute name and add a set of elements instead

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p >
  <node>
    <e a="1"/>
    <e a="2"/>
  </node>
  <a>
    <c value="-3" v="RRR_1"/>
    <c value="1" v="RRR_2"/>
    <c value="11" v="v1"/>
    <c value="12" v="v2"/>
  </a>
</p>
```

I would like to find all c elements whose v attributes values start with RRR and remove them
Then I would like to append at the end the following c nodes

```
  <c value="123" v="RRR_134"/>
  <c value="456" v="RRR_233"/>
  <c value="789" v="RRR_900"/>
```

So the final XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p >
  <node>
    <e a="1"/>
    <e a="2"/>
  </node>
  <a>
    <c value="11" v="v1"/>
    <c value="12" v="v2"/>
    <c value="123" v="RRR_134"/>
    <c value="456" v="RRR_233"/>
    <c value="789" v="RRR_900"/>
  </a>
</p>
```

I wrote the following XSL to remove the c nodes with v attribute starting with RRR - however how do I change the same XSL to also add the required elements at the end. I can write another XSL sheet to do it but wondering if it is possible to do it in the same XSLT file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/p/a/c[starts-with(@v, 'RRR')]"></xsl:template>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- remove new lines for a deleted element -->
  <xsl:template match="*/text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add the nodes after the last `c` element like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/p/a/c[starts-with(@v, 'RRR')]"/>
  <!-- identity transform --> 
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="c[position()=last()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <c value="123" v="RRR_134"/>
    <c value="456" v="RRR_233"/>
    <c value="789" v="RRR_900"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML this produces the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
  <node>
    <e a="1"/>
    <e a="2"/>
  </node>
  <a>
    <c value="11" v="v1"/>
    <c value="12" v="v2"/>
    <c value="123" v="RRR_134"/>
    <c value="456" v="RRR_233"/>
    <c value="789" v="RRR_900"/>
  </a>
</p>
```

I've also removed the template to remove the newlines for deleted elements and added `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instead and an `xsl:output` with the attribute `indent="yes"` to produce an indented output.
The template matching the last `c` element copies this element and just writes the additional `c` nodes afterwards.